# React-Native-Reanimated: error: node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\index.ts:

Tags: android, react-native, node-modules, react-native-reanimated

I was making new project and I can't run the android emulator with this error.

[image]

[image]

It is located at 'node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\index.ts' and this is just the code there:

```
// tree-shaken side effects
import './reanimated2/js-reanimated/global';

// @ts-ignore backward compatibility with treeshaking
export * from './reanimated1';
export * from './reanimated2';
export * as default from './Animated';
```

[image]

Im not sure what to do, please help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I also search for an answer and this worked for me.

Visit this expo reanimated docs link https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/reanimated/#installation

and I added this in my 'babel.config.js' file

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
    plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
  };
};
```

I think the presets depends if you are using expo. Here is the original code given by the docs:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
  };
};
```

you can see that I used my default preset which is module:metro.

Comment: I used the original code from the docs for `babel.config.js` and ran `npx expo start --clear` which cleared the bundler cache, and everything worked again.

Answer (score 2):

I've been facing this problem for about 12 long hours, and the solution for this problem was simply to

1. Copy and paste this code below inside the *babel.config.js* file.

   ```
     return {
       presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
       plugins: ["react-native-reanimated/plugin"],
     };
   };
   ```
2. Run your application using `npx expo start -c`

Answer (score 1):

I ran this command `expo start -c` everything was working fine. After that, I've stopped the app with `Ctrl+c` and run a normal `npm start` and there were no problems with it since

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue , This version works for me

```
    "react-native-reanimated": "2.9.1"
```